# Smartedit giving blank page after the login in Hybris Cloud 1905

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

Smartedit giving blank page after the login in Hybris Cloud 1905. I am getting some JS erros in console.

vendor_chunk.js:2 GET https://api.cmlp705ek-wiprolimi1-d1-public.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com/merchandisingsmartedit/merchandisingsmartedit/js/merchandisingsmarteditContainer.js 500

Comment: You need to share more detail, such as backend and browser console logs.